# Text is not center Aligned in Rounded UI Button - ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uibutton

I have made a floating icon using following code.

```
- (void)createFloatingButton
{

UIButton *floatingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
floatingButton.frame = CGRectMake(kScreenWidth-kFloatingButtonSize-kFloatingButtonSize/2, self.view.frame.size.height-kFloatingButtonSize-kFloatingButtonSize/2, kFloatingButtonSize,kFloatingButtonSize);
[floatingButton setBackgroundColor:kNavColor];
floatingButton.layer.cornerRadius = kFloatingButtonSize/2;

//Configre Font and Text
[floatingButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
floatingButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];

[floatingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(floatingButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//Mange Alignment
floatingButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
floatingButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

//Add shadow
floatingButton.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
floatingButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0f);
floatingButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6f;
floatingButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
floatingButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

[self.view addSubview:floatingButton];
}
```

My output is like that:

[image]

I am not able to bring the `+` in center.

Comment: You can use image with + instead of doing all this. Make one image with + itself. Its easy no issue for +

Comment: @Jecky In Image I have to add tap gesture or if I put UIImage Behind UIButton the code increases I dont wan't to use Imgaege.

Comment: "floatingButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;" should be useful.

Comment: @alicanbatur its not working

Comment: If you have to use + as string, you should change font size for best appereance. If you don't have to do this via string, using image will solve your solution.

Comment: that depends on the font as well which you are using actually, because the glyph probably centered properly but inside its bounds the actual `+` symbol is just closer to the font's baseline; you can refine it by either using different font or playing with the edge inset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set UIButton contentEdgeInsets will make your button title adjustments to top, left, bottom, right.

```
floatingButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
```

In your case, it will make title to center

```
floatingButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2, 3, 0);
```

**Note:**  as per your given code kFloatingButtonSize is not mentioned, i checked with kFloatingButtonSize = 50

[image]